# Finding Lower Confidence Bounds in R

Tags: r, confidence-interval

I am attempting to use just the lower bound of the binom.confint command as a variable. Here is what I have:

```
binom.confint(78.85, 83, conf.level = 0.95, methods = "wilson")
```

Which produces:

```
  method     x  n mean     lower     upper
1 wilson 78.85 83 0.95 0.8801199 0.9800683
```

However, I would like just the "lower" value. Is there a way to put just the lower value into a variable so that

```
lwr <- 0.8801199
```

This works, thanks to some help in the comments:

```
binom.confint(...)$lower
```

But I am attempting to do this for an entire data set:

```
binom.confint(data$1, data$2, conf.level = 0.95, method = "wilson")$lower
```

And I get this error:

```
Error in if (any(out)) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

What can I do to make it work for the entire data set?

Comment: `binom.confint(...)$lower` ?

Comment: Something like `lwr <- binom.confint(78.85, 83, conf.level = 0.95, methods = "wilson")[5] ` should work.

Comment: @Sotos I updated thanks to your help. I had tried both but should've clarified I would like to do so for an entire data set.

Comment: ^ @Imo applies to your comment as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to answer my own question by taking out NA values that were causing problems within the dataset. Ultimately, the code that helped was:

```
binom.confint(data$1, data$2, conf.level = 0.95, method = "wilson")$lower
```